# Тип 'strong' для property в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Буквально только что скачал Xcode 4.2 (developer preview), и после создания нового проекта в интерфейсе делегата приложения обнаружил следующий код:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```

Вопрос: что за тип '**strong**'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опытный товарищ предположил что это "жесткая ссылка" из GC.

Comment: Можно по-подробней об этом?

Comment: Поподробней никак, в сборщике мусора есть такое понятие как "жесткая ссылка", лично я не знаю что и как с ней, но вот сотрудник сделал предположение чот возможно это она. В интернетах и на developer.apple.com ничего не нашел =\..

Comment: Нет, это явно не GC - в темплейте для  iOS то же самое :
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

Answer (score 0):

В [Property Declaration Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) о `strong` ничего не сказано. По факту это не документированная черта языка. Возможно, она связана с модификаторами хранения (`__weak`, `__strong`), а может и нет.

Comment: Да и вообще об этом нигде нет ничего. Будем ждать оф. документации от Apple значит.